# How to Use Azure Notification Hub without updating IOS Application

Tags: c#, azure, azure-notificationhub

I am working in Azure notification hub, and the notifications send to the IOS applications. Following ,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-ios-apple-push-notification-apns-get-started

But the problem is my IOS application currently using about 1000 users. So the users do not want update his app. The question is - any option to implement Azure notification hub in IOS application without updating the App.? In my hand device Id stored in DB. And also I have certificates.

I think write a console application and add all device id to azure notification hub. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, it seems to be not possible to migrate from APNS to Azure Notification Hub for your iOS app without any code changes, because you must have to add the Nofication Hub ListenSharedAccess connect string into your app project. Actually, the architecture migration for your app is from Fig 1 to Fig 2, as below, it will cause necessary code changes. Unless there is some mechanism of hot-patching in your app, but it was not allowed by Apple.

Fig 1.

[image]

Fig 2.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can register all your existing device tokens with the Notification Hub using the API of your choice. Then have your app back-end register new tokens with the notification hub as they come in.

Comment: Is any API available for that?